# AD Share Drives Read Only

Tags: active-directory, file-permissions, shares

I recently re organized my users into new OUs. Now the share drives will not let security groups save, and all files open in read only. All security groups have modify permissions to the share and NTFS permissions. The user reorganization was the only change made. Are these related or am I losing it?

Comment: Did you user logged off and back on to test ? as group membership don't refresh during a session.

Comment: Yes. I had them do a full restart with the same result. This also seems to affect users randomly over VPN connections.

Comment: What are the Share permissions? Have you verified the NTFS permissions? Look at the Effective Permissions for an affected user.

Comment: Share are admin = full, security group = modify. NTFS is the same. Effective permissions for affected user are all green except for full control elements.

Comment: Is this affecting one particular user or a group of users? If it's the latter, what do those users have in common? I.e. group membership, OU membership, domain membership, etc. Is it just one computer or multiple?

Comment: It was a handful of users on 4 or 5 shared folders. A colleague of mine found a solve. Microsoft best practice is to set the Share permissions to Everyone = Full Control then restrict permissions on the NTFS. I don't much agree with Microsoft on that.